# Swift package manager configure fetching trigger

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I'm currently working with Swift package manager with all of my dependencies.
Each time I'm switching between branches SPM is fetching all of the dependencies.

(It takes about 5 - 10 min each time).

My question is whether it is possible to configure the SPM to stop fetching each time?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/developing_a_swift_package_in_tandem_with_an_app) can be helpful.

Comment: The Xcode 13 beta seems to be much better at this

Comment: @Maor any solutions found? Still have the issue. SPM should not redownload dependencies because the versions did not changed. Xcode 14 the issue persists.